# spring boot jpa: ddl-auto=create does not create schema

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am running through some problems while creating some integration tests for my Spring Boot application.

Basically it is a Spring Boot 2 project, with the following database test configuration:

```
# [...]
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project2test?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=tester
spring.datasource.password=tester
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
# [...]
```

Below my `User` entity, which maps to `userdetail` table.

```
package com.roberto.model;

// [...]

@Entity
@Table(name = "USERDETAIL")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userID;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<TimeSheet> timeSheets;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORDEXPIRY")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    private Date lastPasswordResetDate;

    @Column(name = "PASS", length = 100)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 100)
    private String pass;

    // more code goes here [...]
}
```

There is also the TimeSheet entity:

```
package com.roberto.model;

// [...]

@Entity
@Table(name = "TIMESHEET")
public class TimeSheet {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SHEETID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="LOCALDATE")
    private LocalDate localDate;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERID")
    private User user;

    // [...] more code goes here...
}
```

UserRepository is a simple JpaRepository

```
package com.roberto.repository;

// [...]

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Despite of having `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` , the userdetail table does not seem to be created while running my tests in the jenkins server.

```
package com.roberto.security.acl;

// [...]

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ACLIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TimeSheetRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private MutableAclService mutableAclService;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "manager", roles={"ADMIN"})
    public void
    givenUserAdminRole_findAllTimeSheets(){
        List<TimeSheet> details = repo.findAll();  // exception is thrown here

        assertNotNull(details);
        assertEquals(1, details.size());
        assertEquals(FIRST_SHEET_ID, details.get(0).getId());
    }
// further tests go here
}
```

Somehow, it does execute properly in my machine. I am running out of patience and I cannot see any other option. Could you please give me any advice? Thanks.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'project2test.userdetail' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1019)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 107 common frames omitted

[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 17.899 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.roberto.security.acl.ACLIntegrationTest
    [ERROR] givenUserAdminRole_findAllTimeSheets(com.roberto.security.acl.ACLIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.319 s  <<< ERROR!
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at com.roberto.security.acl.ACLIntegrationTest.givenUserAdminRole_findAllTimeSheets(ACLIntegrationTest.java:41)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at com.roberto.security.acl.ACLIntegrationTest.givenUserAdminRole_findAllTimeSheets(ACLIntegrationTest.java:41)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'project2test.userdetail' doesn't exist
        at com.roberto.security.acl.ACLIntegrationTest.givenUserAdminRole_findAllTimeSheets(ACLIntegrationTest.java:41)
```

Looking further into the error log, I can see that the same error happens after trying to execute insert SQL statement from `import.sql` file. I am not really sure if this may be meaningful, in theory having `ddl-auto` set to `create` or `create-drop` allows to [execute this file at boot time](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate). Shall I switch it to the [Spring jdbc alternative](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)?

```
2018-07-11 07:48:46.104 DEBUG 9275 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    INSERT INTO userdetail     (USERNAME,   PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME,  SURNAME, EMAIL, ENABLED, PASSWORDEXPIRY) VALUES    ('admin', '{bcrypt}$2a$08$lDnHPz7eUkSi6ao14Twuau08mzhWrL4kyZGGU5xfiGALO/Vxd5DOi', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin@admin.com', 1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')), ('user',  '{bcrypt}$2a$08$UkVvwpULis18S19S5pZFn.YHPZt3oaqHZnDwqbCW9pft6uFtkXKDC', 'user',  'user',  'enabled@user.com',   1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')),   ('disabled', '{bcrypt}$2a$08$UkVvwpULis18S19S5pZFn.YHPZt3oaqHZnDwqbCW9pft6uFtkXKDC', 'user',  'user',  'disabled@user.com',  0, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')),   ('root',  '{noop}test1234',  'root',  'root',  'root@root.com',   1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')),    ('testsha1', '{SHA-1}1dee4b1affb249bc74c20379e60166366b71394f', 'testsha1', 'testsha1', 'testsha1@testsha1.com', 1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')) on duplicate key update username = username
Hibernate: 
    INSERT INTO userdetail     (USERNAME,   PASSWORD, FIRSTNAME,  SURNAME, EMAIL, ENABLED, PASSWORDEXPIRY) VALUES    ('admin', '{bcrypt}$2a$08$lDnHPz7eUkSi6ao14Twuau08mzhWrL4kyZGGU5xfiGALO/Vxd5DOi', 'admin', 'admin', 'admin@admin.com', 1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')), ('user',  '{bcrypt}$2a$08$UkVvwpULis18S19S5pZFn.YHPZt3oaqHZnDwqbCW9pft6uFtkXKDC', 'user',  'user',  'enabled@user.com',   1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')),   ('disabled', '{bcrypt}$2a$08$UkVvwpULis18S19S5pZFn.YHPZt3oaqHZnDwqbCW9pft6uFtkXKDC', 'user',  'user',  'disabled@user.com',  0, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')),   ('root',  '{noop}test1234',  'root',  'root',  'root@root.com',   1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')),    ('testsha1', '{SHA-1}1dee4b1affb249bc74c20379e60166366b71394f', 'testsha1', 'testsha1', 'testsha1@testsha1.com', 1, STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')) on duplicate key update username = username
2018-07-11 07:48:46.107  WARN 9275 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applyImportSources(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:491)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'project2test.userdetail' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

I have also added @EntityScan annotation to force detection of entities but it does not seem to make a big difference.

```
package com.roberto;

// [...]

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.roberto.model"})
public class JwtDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JwtDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

(**IMPORTANT HERE**) Digging even further into jenkins logs, it seems that mysql does not like my User entity definition...

```
2018-07-11 09:29:18.284 DEBUG 10427 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 

    create table userdetail (
       userid bigint not null auto_increment,
        email varchar(50) not null,
        enabled bit not null,
        firstname varchar(50) not null,
        passwordexpiry datetime(6) not null,
        surname varchar(50) not null,
        pass varchar(100) not null,
        username varchar(50) not null,
        primary key (userid)
    ) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: 

    create table userdetail (
       userid bigint not null auto_increment,
        email varchar(50) not null,
        enabled bit not null,
        firstname varchar(50) not null,
        passwordexpiry datetime(6) not null,
        surname varchar(50) not null,
        pass varchar(100) not null,
        username varchar(50) not null,
        primary key (userid)
    ) engine=InnoDB
2018-07-11 09:29:18.285  WARN 10427 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) not null,
        surname varchar(50) not null,
        pass varchar(100) no' at line 6
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:675)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Most likely, Spring could not discover your Entity class. Can you specify the package names of the classes you created?

Comment: Did you annotate your `TimeSheet` class? You're using it at the `User` class.

Comment: @BennettDams : yeah sure there is (I have just added it to the description)

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman : thanks, that seems like a good tip and made me think of adding EntityScan to my app. Anyhow, it does not seem to work. I have also added the package names as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, given the last piece of logs which was pointing to conflicts between JPA entity definition and mysql, I found out two things:

- `password` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) -> easy fix, just renaming the attribute.
- `passwordexpiry datetime(6) not null` is not accepted by MySQL. After reviewing my requirements, I changed lastPasswordResetDate from `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` to `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` (`passwordexpiry date not null`). This may be a related answer (my local ubuntu has mysql v5.7.22, while the aws jenkins machine has mysql v5.5) -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134189

These two changes made my schema be accepted by mysql, and my integration test to pass.